# Send HTTP POST to another website from my site

Tags: http, post, request

I am trying to send http post request from my site to another site

This is the detail i have the action page i have but its not below
POST COMMENT;

```
name=user&pass=password&form_build_id=form-od3MFMsKIL_5vCQtPmiv0AVf0tFwBuWj6iW7eP2-8&form_id=user_login_block&op=Log+in
```

Then on my site
I placed a html code:

```
<form action="http://sitename.com" method="post">
  <input name="user" pass="pass" form_build_id="form-od3MFMsKIL_5vCQtPmiv0AVf0tFwBuWj6iW7eP2-8" form_id="user_login_block&op=Log+in" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then when i send submit it goes to the login page but it doesnt fill in the user and pass.

Can someone tell me what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing `<input>` tags.
You need to have a separate `<input>` tag for each value in the POST:

```
<input name="name" value="user" />
...
```

Comment: I placed the tags but its not registering on the action-site.com,

Comment: @user3182036: What request body do you see in the network tab in the dev tools?

Comment: do you know how to auto submit form from html without clicking a button

Comment: @user3182036: You're looking for the `submit()` function.

Comment: this is the code '<div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions"><input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="sumbit()" class="form-submit'

Comment: where do i place it??

Comment: That's a Javascript function on the form object.  You need to call it in code.

Comment: Can you give me an example